# datatables Clickable value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables with data source and dynamic columns which works fine with me, What I am searching for is how to make the second value in the datatable clickable.

Example: I want this value "Saudi Government Sukuk" to be clickable.

Here is the JS code

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
var table = $('#' + $('.bondsListTable').attr('id')).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-sm' },
        { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn-sm' },
        { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-sm' },
        { extend: 'pdfHtml5', className: 'btn-sm' },
        { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm' },
    ],
    //"serverSide": true,
    //"processing": true,

    "paging":true,
    data: e.detail.data,
    columns: e.detail.columns,
    responsive: {
        details: { 
            type: 'column'
        }
    },
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        HandleDatatableSearchBar();
        HandleDt_Buttons();
        GenerateShowAndHideCols(e.detail.columns);
        ShowHide();
    }
});
```

DataSource Array Sample

```
  [
    ["", "Saudi Government Sukuk", 1, "June 30, 2017", "Kingdom of Saudi Arabia", "N/A", "0", "Murabaha", "Saudi Arabia", "Announced", "N/A", 0, "N/A", "Projects ", "Domestic", "xssw21", "0", "0", "Sovereign ", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "Saudi Arabia", "Financial Services", "N/A", "has Prices", "N/A", "kingdom of Saudi Arabia"],
    ["", "MAR", 1, "April 30, 2017", "MAR SUKUK LIMITED", "N/A", "0.50 B", "Wakalah;Mudarabah", "Egypt", "Announced", "Irish SE", 0, "N/A", "Real Estate,Financial Portfolio", "International", "XS5155487155FK", "0.50 B", "0.50 B", "Corporate", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "Qatar", "Islamic Banks", "N/A", "No Prices", " moodys A1", "Masraf Al Rayan"],
    ["", "AlKifah", 1, "April 30, 2017", "Not Disclosed", "April 30, 2022", "0.75 B", "Murabaha;Mudarabah", "Saudi Arabia", "Announced", "N/A", 0, "N/A", "Share in Originator Business,Commodities", "Domestic", "XS124454884848FK", "0.20 B", "0.75 B", "Corporate", "N/A", "N/A", "FLT", "Saudi Arabia", "Engineering-Construction", "N/A", "No Prices", "N/A", "Al Kifah Holding Company"]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It
adding columndefs to add class to my preferred column then catch my column by created row by search in every row for the class added then change my html.

```
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
    var table = $('#' + $('.bondsListTable').attr('id')).DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-sm' },
            { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn-sm' },
            { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-sm' },
            { extend: 'pdfHtml5', className: 'btn-sm' },
            { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm' },
        ],
        //"serverSide": true,
        //"processing": true,

        "paging":true,
        data: e.detail.data,
        columns: e.detail.columns,
columnDefs: [
            {
              targets: 1,
              className: 'Detailed-Sukuk-Clickable'
            },{
                "targets":  2 ,
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": false,
                className: 'Detailed-Sukuk-WID'
            },
        responsive: {
            details: { 
                type: 'column'
            }
        },"createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {

                let element = $(row).children('.Detailed-Sukuk-Clickable').text();
                let splitted_Element = element.split('-Splitter:');

                $(row).children('.Detailed-Sukuk-Clickable').html('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ShowCompanyDetailsOnClick(' + splitted_Element[1] + ', false)">' + splitted_Element[0] +'</a>');
                        // Add a class to the cell in the second column
                        $(row).children('.Detailed-Sukuk-Clickable').addClass('text-justify');

                        // Add a class to the row
                        $(row).addClass('important');
                    },
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            HandleDatatableSearchBar();
            HandleDt_Buttons();
            GenerateShowAndHideCols(e.detail.columns);
            ShowHide();
        }
    });
```